# How to reference Look UP column in Oledb Command

Tags: ssis

I have a look where on matching i am selecting ONE column from right hand side pane. Output of this Lookup is a oledb command. I need to reference that Column in Query. How it can be done

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your source to reference mapped, you just need to get the looked up value back, yeah?

If so, that's as simple as clicking the checkbox against all the columns you need from your data source. That will then get reflected in the table below the diagram. As you can *sort-of* notice, while my value in the lookup columns is called BlankedKEY, I rename it as lkp_BlankedKey so that if you have need to compare the retrieved key to the source key, that's available to you.

[image: lookup editor]

After checking that box, the new column is available to your OLEDB Command.